# Passing options to grep in ~/.bashrc

Tags: bash, shell, grep

In my ~/.bashrc, I have the following:

```
function grep_shortcut {
    local x="$1" y="$2"
    shift 2
    echo grep $x "$y" "${@-.}"
    grep $x "$y" "${@-.}"
}

function grb {
    grep_shortcut "-Irs --include '*.*rb'" $@
}
```

If I run `grb foo`, the `echo` will print `grep -Irs --include '*.*rb' foo .`, which is what I want, but I get no results from the grep.  I don't understand why.

Anyone?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're passing the string `"-Irs --include '*.*rb'"` as a single argument to `grep`.

Comment: Looks like you're right.  I'll have to figure out how to do this slightly differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `grb foo`, when you run `grep $x "$y" "${@-.}"`, the actual command is:

```
grep "-Irs" "--include" "'*.*rb'" "foo" "."
```

This is a quick way to fix it:

```
#!/bin/bash

function grep_shortcut {
    local x=$1 y=$2
    eval "x=($x)"
    shift 2
    echo grep "${x[@]}" "$y" "${@-.}"
    grep "${x[@]}" "$y" "${@-.}"
}

function grb {
    grep_shortcut "-Irs --include '*.*rb'" "$@"
}

grb foo
```

And this is another way which avoids `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash

function grep_shortcut {
    local x=("${@:2:$1}"); shift "$(( 1 + $1 ))"
    local y=$1; shift
    echo grep "${x[@]}" "$y" "${@-.}"
    grep "${x[@]}" "$y" "${@-.}"
}

function grb {
    grep_shortcut 3 -Irs --include '*.*rb' "$@"
}

grb foo
```